# How to find specific text in double quotes in my string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

Say I have the following sentence or string.

```
[mywall status="ok"]
```

My question is. How can I test the occurance of "status" in that sentence and change the word "ok" to something else, and this is using jQuery. Is there a regular expression that does this?

*I have no knowledge of regular expressions, and made google search before posting this question.

**EDIT**

Yes but what if the word "ok" does not have to be "ok" always, it's just a variable. I want to catch the word in quotes whatever it is, but it must be after "status=... " Thanks

Comment: Try `'[mywall status="ok"]'.replace(/(status=)"ok"/, '$1"false"')`

Comment: Yes but what if the word "ok" does not have to be "ok" always, it's just a variable. I want to catch the word in quotes whatever it is, but it must be after "status=... " Thanks

Comment: try `var status = '[mywall status="ok"]'.match(/(status=)"(.*?)"/)[2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
var result = s.replace(/(status=")[^"]+/, '$1word');
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate your string with `"` delimiter ,then get the second element that contains Ok , replace it by the value you want and join using `"` as it was at beginning:

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/23thg/)

```
var x = '[mywall status="ok"]';

var y = x.split('"');

y[1]='OOOK';//this element contains Ok and will be replaced by OOOK

alert(y.join('"'));
```